# Pyspark data frame write to sql server performance issue

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to export hive table into sql server using pyspark. Please look on below code.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import HiveContext
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.jars', '/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/jars/sqljdbc42.jar')
sc = SparkContext()
hc = HiveContext(sc)
df = hive.sql("SELECT * FROM db.table where currentrecordindicator='Y' limit 1000000")
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("jdbc")
.option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://ser:1433;databasename=db1")
.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
.option("dbtable", "stg.table")
.option("batchsize","20000")
.option("user","user")
.option("password","pws")
.option("numpartitions","5").save()
```

Used below spark-submit command to run.

```
 spark-submit --master yarn 
 --num-executors 5 
 --executor-cores 15 
 --executor-memory 10g  
 --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME=/dev/null 
 --conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=200  
 spark_table.py
```

Please find below log of above job.

```
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 11) in 56637 ms on p05.pd.com (executor 1) (19/20)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) in 56651 ms on p05.pd.com (executor 1) (20/20)
INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) finished in 56.681 s
INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
INFO DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
INFO DAGScheduler: running: Set()
INFO DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ResultStage 1)
INFO DAGScheduler: failed: Set()
INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[9] at save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in memory (estimated size 43.2 KB, free 365.3 MB)
INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 15.4 KB, free 365.3 MB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on X.X.X.X.50:57398 (size: 15.4 KB, free: 366.2 MB)
INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[9] at save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0)
INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 20, p03.pd.com, executor 4, partition 0, NODE_LOCAL, 5963 bytes)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on p03.pd.com:45793 (size: 15.4 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to X.X.X.X:60768
**INFO MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 0 is 253 bytes**
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 20) in 431138 ms on p03.pd.com (executor 4) (1/1)
INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) finished in 431.140 s
INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: save at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, took 488.105556 s
INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

After this INFO in log "**INFO MapOutputTrackerMaster: Size of output statuses for shuffle 0 is 253 bytes**" my job hangs for 8 minutes and completed.

I am thinking that some where my configuration went wrong and it is taking long time to export 1M records.

Can some one help me to improve performance of my job. I have 31M records with 9GB data in table here i have shown example with 1M records.

Note: In current prod environment we are using pyodbc to export which is very slow in reading hive table because of that we are doing some POC on spark in performance improvement.

Please look on [Performance issue while reading data from hive using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931835/performance-issue-while-reading-data-from-hive-using-python)

Thank you.

Comment: With the help of df.repartition(5) and numpartitions=5 helped me to reduce time.

Comment: are you using this https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector ?

Comment: No i am not using it. Looks like there is connector now for pyspark and it will be more powerful.